# Python return only a tuple in a list

Tags: python

I was wondering how I could select only a tuple in a list where there could be numbers and other things in Python 3.

How to do it if the list looks like this?

```
>> [5433, (32, 54, 122)]
(32, 54, 122) #expected result
```

I want to ignore the first number and return only the tuple of integers.

Any ideas?

Comment: `[t for t in l if isinstance(t, tuple)]` - This will return list of all tuples.

Comment: Does the tuple always appear in the second position? Can there be multiple tuples?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Yes this worked perfectly

Comment: @interjay no it can be multiple tuples, it can appear everywhere but there could be some numbers that are not tuples in it that I need to remove.

Comment: @Sia Read about filters, they can help you.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I'll check them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
originalList=[5433, (32, 54, 122)]
newList=[item for item in originalList if isinstance(item,tuple)]
```

Now newList is a collection of all tuples from originalList.